# SQL: select a new column that true if row (in another table) exist

Tags: mysql, sql

**I have tables that have columns look like this:**

```
 Customer: cid, blah

 Product: pid, blah

 Order: cid, pid
```

**I want the result table that have these columns:**

cid, pid, (this column is 'true' when have (cid,pid) of that row in Order otherwise 'false')

**for example:**

**customer**

```
1 blah

2 blah

3 blah
```

**product**

```
1 blah

2 blah

3 blah

4 blah
```

**order**

```
1 2

1 3

2 1

2 4

3 3
```

**I want to find the sql query that have this result:**

```
1 1 false

1 2 true

1 3 true

1 4 false

2 1 true

2 2 false

2 3 false

2 4 true

3 1 false

3 2 false

3 3 true

3 4 false
```

I'm trying to figure out that query but it is limited to my knowledge. Anyone know how to write that query?

// **sorry, forget to mention that I want the blah from customer and product in the result as well**

```
cid, blah, pid, blah, true/false
```

Comment: Please read & act on [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may `cross` and `left` joins and `case..when` conditional statement as :

```
   select c.cid, p.pid,  
          ( case when o.cid*o.pid > 0 then 'true' else 'false' end ) 
                    as flag
     from product p
    cross join customer c
    left join order_ o on o.cid = c.cid and o.pid = p.pid   
   order by c.cid, p.pid;
```

*P.S. **order** is a keyword, so I replaced that with **order_***

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/DBR50862)

Comment: +1 as this is the best approach. However, I don't think that `coalesce(o.cid,0)*coalesce(o.pid,0)` is needed. Checking on any one field is enough, as your left join is based on two conditions (two columns).

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT C.CID,P.PID,
  CASE WHEN C.CID,P.PID IN 
   (SELECT CID,PID from 
  ORDER)
  THEN "TRUE" END CASE
   CASE WHEN C.CID,P.PID NOT IN 
     (SELECT CID,PID from
   ORDER)
     THEN "FALSE" END CASE
          FROM CUSTOMER C,PRODUCT P ;
```

> You need a case statement for that.

Answer (score 0):

this is the simplest way :

```
(
SELECT O.cid, O.pid, 'true'
FROM order O 
Where (O.cid, O.pid) in
    (SELECT C.cid, p.pid, 
    FROM customer C CROSS JOIN product P)
)
UNION
(
SELECT O.cid, O.pid, 'false'
FROM order O 
Where (O.cid, O.pid) not in
    (SELECT C.cid, p.pid, 
    FROM customer C CROSS JOIN product P)
)
```

Comment: I think the code under the UNION is not work.
There aren't any row in O that not in C cross join P.
I think it should be `customer C CROSS JOIN product P` instead of `order O`.

Comment: did you execute it?